# How can I set the current Thread's locale?

Tags: swift, set, locale

In C#, one can set the current thread's "culture" (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr");`)

Is something similar possible in Swift (5+)? How can one write Swift code to change the current locale?

Comment: Locale in iOS  is device based not thread based.

Comment: Use the `Locale` class.

Comment: Matt, well, how do I modify in Swift the current device's locale? (I did say "similar" suspecting some such difference)

Maddy, do you mean supplying a locale to every function like `lowercased()`, `uppercased()`? This is one thing I would like to avoid doing.

Comment: You don’t set the locale of a thread. In those rare cases that you need to override the device’s locale for some reason, you do so on the object that has a `locale` property (e.g. a `DateFormatter`, a `NumberFormatter`, etc.). If you describe what behavior you’re trying to achieve with a locale other than the device’s locale, we can probably offer you more concrete counsel. But, even though you don’t want to, if you need to do a lot of operations with a locale other than the current one, you’ll have to do this function by function.

Comment: The concrete behavior I'm trying to achieve is quite simple: not having to supply a locale property on every "localizable" call (this may entail changing a lot of code) but rather changing the current default locale in my program without changing the device's setting and, I suppose, restarting the program, just as I can do with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`  in C#, the example I gave.